# How to get a random value from a string array in android?

Tags: java, android, random, arrays

In my values.xml file, I have an array, like this;

```xml
<string-array name="animals-array">
    <item>Cow</item>
    <item>Pig</item>
    <item>Bird</item>
    <item>Sheep</item>
</string-array>
```

In my app, I want to get one of these values at random, but I am unsure how to do this. I have looked at

[Help in getting String Array from arrays.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453989/help-in-getting-string-array-from-arrays-xml-file)

and this

[Retrieving a random item from ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034370/retreiving-an-item-from-arraylist-at-random)

But how do I retrieve a random item from my list that is defined in the values.xml file?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
String[] array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animals_array);
String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Egor: Shouldn't `String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];` be `String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length - 1)];` to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @OsamaMohammedShaikh, Check the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: Ok it excludes specified value, i.e. n value. I checked Android docs but that was not so clear, so had a doubt. Well thanks for clearing the doubt.

Comment: I want random string but don't want to `repeat`...could you please help...? Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Retrive the Complete String Array from the xml and put it inside an ArrayList using
       `Arrays.asList()` method.

**2.** Use `Math.random()*mArr.size()` function to get a random number. **(mArr is the ArrayList)**

**3.** Then use this random number to get an animal from the ArrayList like

```
   `myArr.get(myrand);`
```

**4.** The reason i suggested the use of ArrayList (ie  Collection framework) cause that will give you **more flexibility**.

Comment: This works too, accepted the other answer because it was first

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] myArrayOfStrings = {"one", "two", "three" } 
Random r = new Random();
String myRandString = r.nextInt(myArrayOfStrings.length );
```