# Android: Placing a random item from a String Array in to Notifications

Tags: android, arrays, alarmmanager, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I want my app to be able to pick a random item from this string array:

```
<string-array name="quote_list">
    <item>Quote 1 </item>
    <item>Quote 2 </item>
    <item>Quote 3</item> </string-array>
```

And send the item off in a notification to the user. (Will be at a time chosen by user, using alarmmanager)

I believe I can generate a random item using the following method. [How to get a random value from a string array in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600001/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-a-string-array-in-android)

Would I start off with something like this?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText(String randomStr);
```

I still don't know really how I would go about placing a random item into a notification. Is it also possible to make it so the items the app chooses do not repeat?

Many Thanks,

-Mike

Comment: at what specific time to you get stuck? What problem are you having? Have you read the android notification documentation?

Answer (score 0):

First get the random value from the string array (like the link you mentioned):

```
String[] array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animals_array);
String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
```

Then use `NotificationManager` to show `randomStr` to user:

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

int icon = R.drawable.icon4;        
CharSequence tickerText = "ticker-text";  
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
Context context = getApplicationContext();     
CharSequence contentTitle = "MyTitle";  
CharSequence contentText = randomStr;      
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```