# How to send notification from an array in android without repeating values

Tags: android, arrays, alarmmanager, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I am fairly new to android development guys, so please bear with me.

In my app I want to send notification to the user in frequent intervals. I already set the intervals through alarm manager and used broadcastReciever to send the notifications.

And i followed this method [Android: Placing a random item from a String Array in to Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664823/android-placing-a-random-item-from-a-string-array-in-to-notifications) to randomly iterate value through the array and send notification.But it often repeats the same values from array, so how to make it not repeat the values once it is send through notification.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you delete the item from the array when sent?

Comment: Simple: stop randomly iterating.

Comment: @cuoka I need to use those item again, so deleting is not an option

Comment: @XaverKapeller ok, i'll try doing that

Comment: @HaarisAhamed you could use an array of booleans to keep track of what items have been sent.