# Display Random Text From Array when Button is Pressed

Tags: java, android, xml

From a string array (code below), I want to randomly display one of the strings in a TextView (code below), when a button is pressed (code below). Do I have to use an onClick"sendMessage" and then a random string generator? How would I do this in Java? Many thanks!

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="colorArray">
        <item>Green</item>
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Purple</item>
        <item>Blue</item>
        <item>Orange</item>
        <item>Brown</item>
        <item>Yellow</item>
        <item>White</item>
        <item>Pink</item>
</resources>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE"
        android:textSize="76sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/green_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/green_button"/>
```

Comment: check this link [Get random value from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600001/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-a-string-array-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate random number using function `Random` whose value should not be exceed (array length - 1) using that value get value from string array and display it in your textview.

```
String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorArray);

Random random = new Random();

textView.setText(colors[random.nextInt(colors.length()-1)]);
```

hope this will help.

*Note : This snippet is just an example .pass your variables in it.*

Comment: I tried this code but I get errors that I cannot resolve symbols `random`, `textview`, and `nextInt`

Comment: this is just snippet example now you have to pass your textview variable to it. and random and nextint should work why it is giving you cannot resolve error?

Comment: I imported import java.util.Random;

Comment: But I'm still confused as to where I have to import my textview variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a random number generator for the array indexes (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Put an `onClickListener` on your `Button`. Then, using `Random`, generate a random int, which we will call `randomNumber`.

From there, the process is easy.

1. Check if user has clicked the button via an `onClickListener`
2. If the button is clicked, generate a random number, `randomNumber`, via the `Random` class.
3. Display your random `String` by setting your `EditText`'s text to `colorArray[randomNumber]`