# App crashing when fetching from string ressources

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a string array in the string.xml ressources;

```
<string-array name="errors_signup">
    <item>Successful sign up</item>
    <item>Invalid username!\n(more than 4 characters have to be used)</item>
    <item>Username already taken!\n(Change it)</item>
    <item>Invalid e-mail address!</item>
    <item>E-mail already used!\n(Choose another one)</item>
    <item>Invalid password\n(more than 4 characters have to be used)</item>
    <item>Couldn\'t create the account!\n(try again)</item>
    <item>Passwords are not identical\n</item>
</string-array>
```

And I am trying to fetch it by the following code:

```
private String [] errorsSignup = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.errors_signup);
```

Running the above code immediately crashes the app. Any explanation?
Here is the log:

```
05-06 02:22:18.941: D/dalvikvm(4111): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 111K, 47% free 2913K/5447K, external 1033K/1036K, paused 63ms
05-06 02:22:19.066: W/dalvikvm(4111): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
05-06 02:22:19.073: E/AndroidRuntime(4111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 02:22:19.073: E/AndroidRuntime(4111): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.CheesyDev.penpal/com.CheesyDev.penpal.A1_signup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Could you include the error log in your question please? :) And does the line number being complained the second line of the code you provided?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453989/help-in-getting-string-array-from-arrays-xml-file) may help you.

Comment: So I'm noticing there's a run time exception at A1_signup.java line 65. Could you include this line to the question please? this line has a null variable that you probably aren't expecting to be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what's wrong with the code above:

The resources of the `Activity` aren't available before the `onCreate` method gets called. So, trying to access the resources by initializing the `string array` when instantiating the `Activity` will throw an NPE.

The same issue is deeply explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453989/help-in-getting-string-array-from-arrays-xml-file).

Thanks to [@Rembo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066779/rembo) for this help!