# Fragment not attached to activity when using resource file

Tags: android

I have an activity that loaded a string array directly into it

```
private String[] questions = {"Q1", "Q2", "Q3"};
private String[] answers= {"A1", "A2", "A3"};
```

I wanted to change it to load from a resource file

Resource File named Questions

```
<string-array name="questions">
    <item>Q1</item>
    <item>Q2</item>
    <item>Q3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="answers">
    <item>A1</item>
    <item>A2</item>
    <item>A3</item>
</string-array>
```

Changed the string array to

```
private String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
private String[] answers= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
```

When I changed it to pull the string array from my resource file it gives me

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: My_Fragment{38ad4cd} not attached to Activity
```

Comment: Where do you call getResources()?

Comment: The error means that the fragment has not been attached to the corresponding activity, so maybe this method is called too early?

Comment: try getActivity().getResources()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's going on?

What your actual code does is that it tries to access the resources when the `Fragment` is instantiated, which is wrong because the resources won't be available unless your `Fragment` is attached to some `Activity`.

### Plus

The call `getResources()` is just a shortcut to `getActivity().getResources()`. My guess is that its implementation looks like this:

```
if(isAttached()) {
    return getActivity().getResources();
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Fragment is not attached...");
}
```

## Solution

Move this initialization:

```
private String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
private String[] answers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
```

To your `onCreateView` method:

```
private String[] questions;
private String[] answers;

public void onCreateView(...){
    // ...
    questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
    answers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
    // ...
}
```

### Note

You're safe to move this initialization anywhere in between `onAttach` and `onDetach` callbacks. Check the [fragment life-cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to get a clear idea.

## Similar question but with an activity

[App crashing when fetching from string ressources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23484424/3503855).

Comment: That did the job. Can't believe it was so simple. Thanks!