# Android ContactList app error in setText used ListView

Tags: android, listview, contacts

I am newbe to android app programming here.
i am buidling an android app Contact list having Listview.
error occur in this line
             `outputText.setText(output);`
username.java coding is here`

```
package com.letmedrive;
import com.letmedrive.util.SystemUiHider;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.ListView;
/**
* An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
* status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
*
* @see SystemUiHider
*/





public class Username extends Activity {
public ListView outputText;

/**
 * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
 * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
 */
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

/**
 * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
 * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
 */
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

/**
 * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
 * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
 */
private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

/**
 * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
 */
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

/**
 * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
 */
private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_username);
    ListView outputText = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    fetchcontacts();

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView.animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
}
public void fetchcontacts() {
    String phonenumber = null;
    String email = null;
    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
    Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    //Loop for every contact in the phone
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                output.append("\n First Name:" + name);
                // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI,null,Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ", new String[] { contact_id},null);
                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    phonenumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                    output.append("\n Phone number:" + phonenumber);
                }
                phoneCursor.close();


            }
            output.append("\n");
        }
        outputText.setText(output);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}


/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};

/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the LogCat output.

Comment: its too long cant pbe uploaoded

Comment: I very strongly recommend you read a book about the basics of Java so you can learn how to read stacktraces and interpret the errors the compiler is showing you. Then move on to another book about Android development. Avoid quick, dirty and outdated tutorials on the net, and don't rush things, if you do, you'll eventually end up not understanding the errors you're facing again...

Comment: @2Dee thanks for suggesting me

Answer (score 2):

There is no `setText()` method for a `ListView` object, so `outputText.setText()` will throw an exception along the lines of `method setText not supported for class ListView`.

Perhaps you're setting the text to the wrong object, or you mean to be using an `Adapter` instead? The answer to that would require more knowledge of the project. If you just want to display one large string, use a `TextView` object instead of a `ListView`.

Comment: How to correct that settext in relative support to       List view

Comment: Well you can either look into an ArrayAdapter and use a String array to display each item on a row, or you can replace it with a TextView object and call `textView.setText()` to display the information.

Comment: @balramrexwal this post uses a String-Array from the resources, but you can apply the same Adapter logic to an array you generate yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453989/help-in-getting-string-array-from-arrays-xml-file

Comment: like that textView.setText(output); if it is wrong can you write it pls.