# Listview bringing one item only from the string array in strings.xml

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I am trying to create a `ListView` in android but it is only generating one item on the list.

Here is my code snippet

```
String[] kampala1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.kla);
sitelistview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,kampala1));
```

i need help in getting all strings in the string array I created

string array is

```
<string-array name="kla"> 
   <item>uganda Museum</item>
   <item>Namugongo Museum</item>
   <item>wandegeya Market</item>
   <item>kasubi tombs</item>
   <item>kabaka palace</item>
   <item>kabaka lake</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: You mean to say `kampala1` contains only one item?

Comment: Show us the string array you have in strings.xml please

Comment: You array seems correct and so looks the getResources and setAdapter. Maybe you should give us some more information. Where is that code placed? in onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use hard code string array then use it directly using xml.

Declare your array in strings.xml like this.

```
<string-array name="kla">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
```

and use it in your layout.

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:entries="@array/kla"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array Adapter. Its a good solution with ample scope for flexibility and customisation. Check the example explained in the solution below.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453989/help-in-getting-string-array-from-arrays-xml-file](http://Array%20Adapter%20example)