# get string-array from Strings.xml by a variable

Tags: android

i try this code to get the string from **strings.xml** using variable name. It's working perfectly but i want to access `string-array` in `xml` using variable bt it's not working. Any Help would be appreciated

```
    String name = "app_name";
    int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier (name,"string","com.example.saa.quotes");
    if (identifier!=0){
        array=getResources().getString(identifier);
        Toast.makeText(this, array, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        array=null;//or null or whatever
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not able to acces the Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Please check this link :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453989/help-in-getting-string-array-from-arrays-xml-file/13579275

Comment: The second argument in `getIdentifier()` should be `"array"`, not `"string"`.

Comment: Thankyou it's working .